# Liquid (Shopify) scope questions

Tags: loops, for-loop, scope, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to set two variables outside of a few nested loops (for loops) and then check or reassign the variables inside the for. Basically, I'm trying to check for current_tags and display links to any tags under those tags (in the hierarchy I've got). Shopify seems to only support one level of hierarchy (collections and their associated products), but I'm trying to use these tags to make it look like I've got multiple levels of ways of classifying products. So shirt, then red shirt/brown shirt, then red silk shirt/brown silk shirt, as a shitty example.
Here's some code:

```
{% assign showtag = false %} 

        {% for link in linklists[settings.main_linklist].links %}
              {% if linklists[link.handle] == empty %}

              {% else %}

                    {% for link in linklists[link.handle].links %}
                      {% if linklists[link.handle] == empty %}

                      {% else %}

                          {% for link in linklists[link.handle].links %}                        

                              {% if linklists[link.handle] == empty %}
                              {% else %}
                                    {% capture temp_tag %}{{current_tags.first | replace: '-', ' '}}{% endcapture %}
                                     link {{link.title}}<br> 
                                     temp {{temp_tag}}<br>
                                     {% if showtag == true %}
                                          <li>{{ tag | highlight_active_tag | link_to_tag: tag }}</li>
                                      {% endif %}
                                     {% if link.title == temp_tag}
                                          {% assign showtag = true %}

                                     {% endif %}


                              {% endif %}
                               {% for link in linklists[link.handle].links %}                        
                                    {% capture temp_tag %}{{current_tags.first | replace: '-', ' '}}{% endcapture %}
                                    {% if linklists[link.handle] == empty %}

                                         {% if showtag == true %}
                                                    <li>{{ tag | highlight_active_tag | link_to_tag: tag }}</li>
                                           {% endif %}
                                           {% if link.title == temp_tag %}
                                                    {% assign showtag = true %}

                                          {% endif %}

                                    {% else %}

                                           {% if showtag == true %}
                                                <li>{{ tag | highlight_active_tag | link_to_tag: tag }}</li>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% if link.title == temp_tag %}
                                                {% assign showtag = true %}

                                           {% endif %}


                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}


                          {% endfor %}

                      {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}

              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

The above is a little messy but is properly indented on the website. Anyway, it seems like the variable showtag loses scope and cannot be found in the for loops - any solutions?

Comment: There are code formatting tools - the `{}` button on the tool bar, `CTRL+K`, and indenting by four spaces are all ways to get code to look like code... This question will likely be closed very quickly if you don't add some of the code, because its very difficult to answer without that... you can edit your post by clicking the "edit" link under the tags

Comment: It was late when I posted the question, darthbit. I've updated my post to show a little code. Cheers for the suggestion.

Comment: In order to see where you are at and what is actually failing, I would suggest 1) Updating your forloop "link" vars, so that you have distinct ones for each inner loop e.g. `link`, `childLink`, `grandChildLink`. 2) Output some values within those loops so you can see where you are at, either in the HTML, or comments or console logs if you are working on the live theme.